# Is there a way to convert a grayscale image array into a Tensor to feed to a model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm a real starter in machine learning. But I'm trying to deploy the MNIST character recognition example with a Flask server. I already set up the model, trained it and set up Flask.

I've created a simple HTML canvas where I can draw numbers from 0-9. These are sent via AJAX to my python backend.

In the Python backend, I receive the Base64 Image and decode it to a 255-grayscale array. So I have this giant array with information about the image:

```
[138, 102, 160, 120, 54, 173, 105, 214, 173, 106, 41, 154, 129, 239, 233, 158, 6, 218, 177, 238, 184, 137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10, 0, 0, 0, 13, 73, 72, 68, 82, 0, 0, 1, 144, 0, 0, 1, 144, 8, 6, 0, 0, 0, 128, 191, 54, 204, 0, 0, 28, 81, 73, 68, 65, 84, 120, 94, 237, 221, 9, 172, 109, 87, 89, 7, 240, 63, 145, 72, 152, 154, 128, 128, 168, 16, 32, 21, 80, 169, 80, 202, 148, 20, 16, 43, 161, 45, 80, 160, 140, 50, 180, 34, 29, 24, 210, 42, 2, 130, 180, 1, 25, 211, 34, 163, 96, 27, 134, 14, 32, 101, 146, 25, 139, 165, 45, 40, 164, 12, 134, 22, 104, 9, 160, 76, 13, 40, 168, 164, 32, 36, 101, 10, 4, 131, 89, 118, 95, 122, 237, 240, 222, 121, 251, 158, 179, 246, 218, 107, 255, 78, 242, 114, 31, 183, 103, 237, 181, 190, 223, 183, 30, 255, 220, 187, 207, 222, 251, 26, 241, 34, 64, 128, 0, 1, 2, 35, 4, 174, 49, 98, 140, 33, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 32, 2, 196, 38, 32, 64, 128, 0, 129, 81, 2, 2, 100, 20, 155, 65, 4, 8, 16, 32, 32, 64, 236, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 24, 37, 32, 64, 70, 177, 25, 68, 128, 0, 1, 2, 2, 196, 30, 32, 64, 128, 0, 129, 81, 2, 2, 100, 20, 155, 65, 4, 8, 16, 32, 32, 64, 236, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 24, 37, 32, 64, 70, 177, 25, 68, 128, 0, 1, 2, 2, 196, 30, 32, 64, 128, 0, 129, 81, 2, 2, 100, 20, 155, 65, 4, 8, 16, 32, 32, 64, 236, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 24, 37, 32, 64, 70, 177, 25, 68, 128, 0, 1, 2, 2, 196, 30, 32, 64, 128, 0, 129, 81, 2, 2, 100, 20, 155, 65, 4, 8, 16, 32, 32, 64, 236, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 24, 37, 32, 64, 70, 177, 25, 68, 128, 0, 1, 2, 2, 196, 30, 32, 64, 128, 0, 129, 81, 2, 2, 100, 20, 155, 65, 4, 8, 16, 32, 32, 64, 236, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 24, 37, 32, 64, 70, 177, 25, 68, 128, 0, 1, 2, 2, 196, 30, 32, 64, 128, 0, 129, 81, 2, 2, 100, 20, 155, 65, 4, 8, 16, 32, 32, 64, 236, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 24, 37, 32, 64, 70, 177, 25, 68, 128, 0, 1, 2, 2, 196, 30, 32, 64, 128, 0, 129, 81, 2, 2, 100, 20, 155, 65, 4, 8, 16, 32, 32, 64, 236, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 24, 37, 32, 64, 70, 177, 25, 68, 128, 0, 1, 2, 2, 196, 30, 32, 64, 128, 0, 129, 81, 2, 2, 100, 20, 155, 65, 4, 8, 16, 32, 32, 64, 236, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 24, 37, 32, 64, 70, 177, 25, 68, 128, 0, 1, 2, 2, 196, 30, 32, 64, 128, 0, 129, 81, 2, 2, 100, 20, 155, 65, 4, 8, 16, 32, 32, 64, 236, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 24, 37, 32, 64, 70, 177, 25, 68, 128, 0, 1, 2, 2, 196, 30, 32, 64, 128, 0, 129, 81, 2, 2, 100, 20, 155, 65, 4, 8, 16, 32, 32, 64, 236, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 24, 37, 32, 64, 70, 177, 25, 68, 128, 0, 1, 2, 2, 196, 30, 32, 64, 128, 0, 129, 81, 2, 2, 100, 20, 155, 65, 4, 8, 16, 32, 32, 64, 236, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 24, 37, 32, 64, 70, 177, 25, 68, 128, 0, 1, 2, 2, 196, 30, 32, 64, 128, 0, 129, 81, 2, 2, 100, 20, 155, 65, 4, 8, 16, 32, 32, 64, 236, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 24, 37, 32, 64, 70, 177, 25, 68, 128, 0, 1, 2, 2, 196, 30, 32, 64, 128, 0, 129, 81, 2, 2, 100, 20, 155, 65, 4, 8, 16, 32, 32, 64, 236, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 24, 37, 32, 64, 70, 177, 25, 68, 128, 0, 1, 2, 2, 196, 30, 32, 64, 128, 0, 129, 81, 2, 2, 100, 20, 155, 65, 4, 8, 16, 32, 32, 64, 236, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 24, 37, 32, 64, 70, 177, 25, 68, 128, 0, 1, 2, 2, 196, 30, 32, 64, 128, 0, 129, 81, 2, 2, 100, 20, 155, 65, 4, 8, 16, 32, 32, 64, 236, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 24, 37, 32, 64, 70, 177, 25, 68, 128, 0, 1, 2, 2, 196, 30]
```

But I can't find a way to reshape this array so I can feed it into my tensorflow model, which requires the following input:

`Tensor("shape=(28, 28, 1), dtype=float32)`

Can you help me find a way to transform this array in Python to a tensor of appropriate size?

Thanks already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code that should work.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
data = [138, 102, 160, 120, 54, 173, 105, 214, 173, 106, 41, 154, 129, 239, 233, 158, 6, 218, 177, 238, 184, 137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10, 0, 0, 0, 13, 73, 72, 68, 82, 0, 0, 1, 144, 0, 0, 1, 144, 8, 6, 0, 0, 0, 128, 191, 54, 204, 0, 0, 28, 81, 73, 68, 65, 84, 120, 94, 237, 221, 9, 172, 109, 87, 89, 7, 240, 63, 145, 72, 152, 154, 128, 128, 168, 16, 32, 21, 80, 169, 80, 202, 148, 20, 16, 43, 161, 45, 80, 160, 140, 50, 180, 34, 29, 24, 210, 42, 2, 130, 180, 1, 25, 211, 34, 163, 96, 27, 134, 14, 32, 101, 146, 25, 139, 165, 45, 40, 164, 12, 134, 22, 104, 9, 160, 76, 13, 40, 168, 164, 32, 36, 101, 10, 4, 131, 89, 118, 95, 122, 237, 240, 222, 121, 251, 158, 179, 246, 218, 107, 255, 78, 242, 114, 31, 183, 103, 237, 181, 190, 223, 183, 30, 255, 220, 187, 207, 222, 251, 26, 241, 34, 64, 128, 0, 1, 2, 35, 4, 174, 49, 98, 140, 33, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 32, 2, 196, 38, 32, 64, 128, 0, 129, 81, 2, 2, 100, 20, 155, 65, 4, 8, 16, 32, 32, 64, 236, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 24, 37, 32, 64, 70, 177, 25, 68, 128, 0, 1, 2, 2, 196, 30, 32, 64, 128, 0, 129, 81, 2, 2, 100, 20, 155, 65, 4, 8, 16, 32, 32, 64, 236, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 24, 37, 32, 64, 70, 177, 25, 68, 128, 0, 1, 2, 2, 196, 30, 32, 64, 128, 0, 129, 81, 2, 2, 100, 20, 155, 65, 4, 8, 16, 32, 32, 64, 236, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 24, 37, 32, 64, 70, 177, 25, 68, 128, 0, 1, 2, 2, 196, 30, 32, 64, 128, 0, 129, 81, 2, 2, 100, 20, 155, 65, 4, 8, 16, 32, 32, 64, 236, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 24, 37, 32, 64, 70, 177, 25, 68, 128, 0, 1, 2, 2, 196, 30, 32, 64, 128, 0, 129, 81, 2, 2, 100, 20, 155, 65, 4, 8, 16, 32, 32, 64, 236, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 24, 37, 32, 64, 70, 177, 25, 68, 128, 0, 1, 2, 2, 196, 30, 32, 64, 128, 0, 129, 81, 2, 2, 100, 20, 155, 65, 4, 8, 16, 32, 32, 64, 236, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 24, 37, 32, 64, 70, 177, 25, 68, 128, 0, 1, 2, 2, 196, 30, 32, 64, 128, 0, 129, 81, 2, 2, 100, 20, 155, 65, 4, 8, 16, 32, 32, 64, 236, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 24, 37, 32, 64, 70, 177, 25, 68, 128, 0, 1, 2, 2, 196, 30, 32, 64, 128, 0, 129, 81, 2, 2, 100, 20, 155, 65, 4, 8, 16, 32, 32, 64, 236, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 24, 37, 32, 64, 70, 177, 25, 68, 128, 0, 1, 2, 2, 196, 30, 32, 64, 128, 0, 129, 81, 2, 2, 100, 20, 155, 65, 4, 8, 16, 32, 32, 64, 236, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 24, 37, 32, 64, 70, 177, 25, 68, 128, 0, 1, 2, 2, 196, 30, 32, 64, 128, 0, 129, 81, 2, 2, 100, 20, 155, 65, 4, 8, 16, 32, 32, 64, 236, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 24, 37, 32, 64, 70, 177, 25, 68, 128, 0, 1, 2, 2, 196, 30, 32, 64, 128, 0, 129, 81, 2, 2, 100, 20, 155, 65, 4, 8, 16, 32, 32, 64, 236, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 24, 37, 32, 64, 70, 177, 25, 68, 128, 0, 1, 2, 2, 196, 30, 32, 64, 128, 0, 129, 81, 2, 2, 100, 20, 155, 65, 4, 8, 16, 32, 32, 64, 236, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 24, 37, 32, 64, 70, 177, 25, 68, 128, 0, 1, 2, 2, 196, 30, 32, 64, 128, 0, 129, 81, 2, 2, 100, 20, 155, 65, 4, 8, 16, 32, 32, 64, 236, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 24, 37, 32, 64, 70, 177, 25, 68, 128, 0, 1, 2, 2, 196, 30, 32, 64, 128, 0, 129, 81, 2, 2, 100, 20, 155, 65, 4, 8, 16, 32, 32, 64, 236, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 24, 37, 32, 64, 70, 177, 25, 68, 128, 0, 1, 2, 2, 196, 30, 32, 64, 128, 0, 129, 81, 2, 2, 100, 20, 155, 65, 4, 8, 16, 32, 32, 64, 236, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 24, 37, 32, 64, 70, 177, 25, 68, 128, 0, 1, 2, 2, 196, 30]
data = np.array(data).reshape(28,28,1)
```

At this point you should be able to use a tensorflow model on this, but if for some reason it does not accept the numpy array, you can try

```
data = tf.convert_to_tensor(data)
```

This will turn the numpy array into a tensorflow tensor. Hope that helps!